# Efficient group distinct count in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have the following data and I would like to know `How many account that has LogCounts >= 7`

| Account | LogCounts |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | 2 |
| BBB | 7 |
| AAA | 7 |
| AAA | 8 |
| AAA | 3 |
| CCC | 2 |

Here is my working MongoDB pipeline

```
[
    {
        '$match': {
            'LogCounts': {
                '$gt': 6
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$project': {
            'Account': 1
        }
    }, {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$Account'
        }
    }, {
        '$count': 'FinalAccountCounts'
    }
]
```

But it took about 5 minutes for ~800 million records collection. I'd like to know if there's any better, faster or more efficient to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Having an index on the field used with the `$match` stage filter will help. The `$project` stage before `$group` is not required.

Answer (score 0):

From a query perspective you are pretty much as efficient as you can be, this is under the assumption you have an index on `LogCounts`.

What you can try is to split your query into in different ranges of `LogCounts` values, this will require prior knowledge of your data distribution. But using this approach you can "map - reduce" the query results. This approach will not help much if the cardinality is extremely low, i.e `LogCount` has max value of 7 for example

Let's assume for a second `LogCounts` can only be in the range of 7 to 21. i.e in `[7,8,9,10,...,20,21]` with equal distribution for each value.
In this case you could execute `x` queries each of them only querying a certain range of the values:

for example 5 queries at once will look like:

```
// in nodejs, all queries are executed at once.
const results = await Promise.all([
    db.collection.aggregate([ { match: { LogCounts: {$gt: 7, $lte: 10} }}, ...restOfPipeline]),
    db.collection.aggregate([ { match: { LogCounts: {$gt: 10, $lte: 13} }}, ...restOfPipeline]),
    db.collection.aggregate([ { match: { LogCounts: {$gt: 13, $lte: 16} }}, ...restOfPipeline]),
    db.collection.aggregate([ { match: { LogCounts: {$gt: 16, $lte: 19} }}, ...restOfPipeline]),
    db.collection.aggregate([ { match: { LogCounts: {$gt: 19, $lte: 21} }}, ...restOfPipeline]),
])

// now merge results in memory.
```

I can tell you that from testing this approach on a 800M collection on a dataset with `string` values and high cardinality my 1 query ran in 3min, when I split it to 2 queries I managed to run it in 2.1min including the "reduce" part in memory.

Obviously optimization this will require trial an error as you have several parameters to consider, # of buckets, value cardinality for query optimization ( one query can be 7 to 10 and one query 10 to 21 depending on distribution ), # of results etc

If you do end up choosing my approach I'd be happy to get an update after some testing.

Comment: thx. But I only want to get the final count. So map-reduce solution might not be the ideal to my problem. My query obviously had lots of overhead, so I'm looking for something like "short-cut". Once an account matched, it will be skipped during the process. But I'm not sure if it's even possible.

Comment: Yes I know, you can merge that in memory. There is no alternative or "quick win" to what you're asking.